# Calling set-returning function with each element in array

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a set-returning function (SRF) that accepts an integer argument and returns a set of rows from a table. I call it using `SELECT * FROM tst.mySRF(3);`, and then manipulate the returned value as if it were a table.

What I would like to do is to execute it on each element of an array; however, when I call it using `SELECT * FROM tst.mySRF(unnest(array[3,4]));`, an error is returned "set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set". If I instead call it using `SELECT tst.mySRF(unnest(array[3,4]));`, I get a set of the type `tst.tbl`.

Table definition:

```
DROP TABLE tst.tbl CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE tst.tbl (
    id  serial  NOT NULL,
    txt text    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO tst.tbl(txt) VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d');
```

Function definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tst.mySRF(
    IN  p_id            integer
)
    RETURNS setof tst.tbl
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $body$
        DECLARE
        BEGIN
            RETURN QUERY
                SELECT id, txt
                FROM tst.tbl
                WHERE id = p_id;
        END;
    $body$;
```

Calls:

- `SELECT * FROM tst.mySRF(3)` returns a table, as expected.
- `SELECT tst.mySRF(unnest(array[3,4]))` returns a table with a single column of the type `tst.tbl`, as expected.
- `SELECT * FROM tst.mySRF(unnest(array[3,4]))` returns the error described above, I had expected a table.

Comment: Yes. What you wrote is correct. And what is your question? You can't run select * from function(function()) where inner function returns recordset.

Comment: The question would be how execute an a function for each element of an array and obtain a table, without using a series of UNION statements.

Comment: Well, you showed it - select function(other_function()). If you, for whatever reason, cannot do it like this, on 9.3 you can use LATERAL, and in previous version - use workaroud I described in here: http://www.depesz.com/2012/08/19/waiting-for-9-3-implement-sql-standard-lateral-subqueries/

Comment: @depesz But the table returned by select function(other_function()) is a one column table of tst.tbl rows. How do I convert it to multi-column table of the type tst.tbl? Or does that require the 9.3 functionality you mentioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the "table of single column" problem, you need to explicitly expand the SRF results  with the `(row).*` notation

```
 SELECT (tst.mySRF(unnest(array[3,4]))).*;
```

If I understood @depesz, `LATERAL` will provide a more efficient or straightforward way to achieve the same result.